# Python Django 1.6 execute function for every request before getting to view

Tags: python, django

I'm writing some API functionality for my project using Python 3.4 and Django 1.6. 
All functionality works fine, but I want execute one function for all that kind of requests.
For Example: I have following urls.py file in my API application in Django project

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^getposts', 'Postigs.views.get_posts', name='getPosts'),
    url(r'^addpost', 'Postigs.views.add_post', name='addPost'),
    url(r'^addcomment', 'Postigs.views.add_comment', name='addComment'),
)
```

And `views.py` for that URL requests handling.

So is it possible to execute some function for **Example**:

```
def pre_execute(request):
    do_something_before_view_function()
```

I've worked before with many PHP frameworks , there are always some `pre_execute()` function ... also I've worked with ASP.NET MVC , Node.js Express.js , and all have that function which is firing before request action.

I don't believe that Django didn't have it , but I can't find how implement that functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Middlewares are what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

example middleware: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py

Answer (score 2):

Like iskorum mentioned above, Middlewares is the answer. Or there is also a chance that you are looking for View Decorators. Here is the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/

Comment: broken link (needs fixing)